# Сумма комиссионных, полученная каждым продавцом за октябрь SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

[image: База данных]

Задание:
Сумма комиссионных, полученная каждым продавцом за октябрь.

```
SELECT salespeople.Sname, SUM(salespeople.comm * orders.Osum) as 'Получено' 
FROM salespeople, orders 
WHERE orders.Sid=salespeople.Sid
```

Comment: Вы ошиблись ресурсом. Тут не решают задания.

Comment: Так как суммы нужны по каждому продавцу отдельно, то к вашему запросу надо добавить group by salespeople.Sname

Comment: @Mike Спасибо, получилось

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT salespeople.Sname, SUM(salespeople.comm * orders.Osum) as 'Получено' 
FROM salespeople, orders 
WHERE orders.Sid=salespeople.Sid AND 
orders.Odate BETWEEN '2019/09/30' AND '2019/11/01'
GROUP BY salespeople.Sname
```